# Replace a string's character other than first two and last two characters with asterik in Robot Framework using regexp

Tags: python-3.x, string, robotframework, regexp-replace

What is pattern used to replace a string's character in Robot framework except that my first two and last two characters alone are retained and only all others characters are replaced.

Example:

> > My Input: RAHMAN/MD SANDID MSTR CHD

> > My Output: RA*********************HD

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def starify(string):
    if len(string) <= 4:
        return string
    head = string[:2]
    tail = string[-2:]
    middle = "*" * (len(string) - 4)
    return head + middle + tail
```

note that you will also have to define what do do when the string is too short (in this case I return as-is, but you might want to raise an exception, or turn the whole sting into * or something.

Comment: Hi @Emile, I wanted the regexp to be used in the robot keyword: "Replace String Using Regexp", anyway Thanks for the effort.